# git bash turns off the backlight on my keyboard. How to fix?

Tags: keyboard, git-bash

- the toggle button for the backlight is the Scroll Lock button
- when I alt-tab out of git bash, backlight stays off until I manually turn it back on
- OS is Windows 10
- doesn't happen in Windows Terminal

Comment: Do you solved it?

Comment: No, thank you for asking!  I tried remapping the key with the Sharpkeys utility, which has worked well in the past, but when I remapped it the old key no longer activated the kb backlight.  I may try it again, but the problem is just annoying, not critical -- mostly I can't use "scroll lock" in Excel with the backlight on.  If you find a solution please let me know!  Best wishes.  Also somehow I can't figure out how to do line breaks in this reply sorry about that.....

Comment: I remapped my Scroll lock using Windows PowerToys to skip my music tracks... so annoying! :P

Answer (score 4):

From the [mintty](https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html) help (on which git bash term is built):

> **Scroll Lock handling**
>
> The ScrollLock key is one of the most useless
> keys on typical PC keyboards as it is mostly ignored by software
> nowadays, and yet has its own LED. However, there are two historic
> features that could be associated with "ScrollLock". One is the VT100
> NoScroll key which would hold output via the terminal, the other is a
> Windows function to switch cursor keys to screen scrolling as still
> used by the Excel program. Mintty provides both features as
> user-definable functions, in two variants each. Functions are
> no-scroll and scroll-mode (referring to those two features) which
> would be reset by any key input, and toggle-no-scroll and
> toggle-scroll-mode which would switch the respective feature on or
> off. These functions can be attached to any user-assignable function
> key or special key, including the ScrollLock key, with setting
> KeyFunctions. Mintty manages the ScrollLock keyboard light to reflect
> either of these functions activated, trying to decouple the light
> indication from the ScrollLock key while in a mintty window.

Each time the mintty window receives focus, this fake keypress is triggered it seems.

Further reading:

> **Manage keyboard LEDs (ManageLEDs=7)**
>
> Mintty manages the keyboard indicator lights (LEDs) for the CapsLock,
> Numlock, and ScrollLock state in order to achieve consistent
> indication. If any of these keys have a user-defined function
> attached, their usage shall not affect the visual keyboard modifier
> indication. Also, if a scroll feature is activated (no-scroll or
> scroll-mode), the ScrollLock indication shall indicate the current
> state of the terminal window. The ScrollLock light is restored to its
> previous state if the terminal window gets out of focus or terminates.
> This setting can disable LED management for ScrollLock (ManageLEDs=3)
> or for all modifiers (ManageLEDs=0).

Which means you should add the line

> ManageLEDs=3
> To your `~/.minttyrc` file.

Comment: Couldn't find ~./minntyrc -- edited "minnty" (no rc, no extension) in git/usr/share/minnty. -- no effect.

But Power Toys did the tricks!

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Yeah, PowerToys is a godsend. However, firstly it's, `~/.minttyrc`, not `~./minntyrc` and secondly, you may need to create it... For some reason mine was there already.

Comment: Another option I find useful is: `ZoomFontWithWindow=no` which prevents the fonts from being zoomed when I drag the window into PowerToys fancy zones causing it to resize.

Comment: I created the file and added the line and it worked, thank you !